How to prove the necessary and sufficient condition for a monotone class to be equal to a sigma-algebra.
I have been studying measure theory recently and have come across a theorem as follows:
Theorem: Let $C$ be a set class.
So the necessary and sufficient conditions for
$M (C)=σ(C)$ are $A ∈ C → A^c ∈ M(C)$
$A, B ∈ C → A ∩ B ∈M(C)$
The monotonic class generated by $C$ is denoted as $M (C)$, and the generated $σ$-algebra is denoted as $σ (C)$.
I want to know how to use these conditions to prove that $M (C)=σ (C)$? From the proof of the monotonic theorem in the book, I think it should be proven that $M (C) $is an algebra (My idea may not be correct),but I am at a loss.Is there any good way to do it?
